# Java: How to get geohash values close to a given geohash value?

Tags: java, geolocation, geohashing

I want to create a function that will create a geohash value from a given latitude and longitude, and then create 4 more geohash values close to it, say within 10 km.

I can convert latitude and longitude into a geohash using:

```
GeoHash geohash = GeoHash.withCharacterPrecision(61.2, 21.5, 12);
String geoHashString = geohash.toBase32();
System.out.println(geoHashString);
```

This gives the geohash `u6zk1jpgf6cu`. How can I create four more geohashes within 10 km of it?

I am using the [ch.hsr.geohash](https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/hsr/geohash/GeoHash.java) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the below logic, it should not be very difficult:

```
List<String> geoHashCalculate(Double lat, Double lng, int precision) {
    GeoHash geohash = GeoHash.withCharacterPrecision(61.2, 21.5, 12);
    String geoHashString = geohash.toBase32();

    List<String> geoHashes = new ArrayList<String>();
    geoHashes.add(geohash);

    for(int i=1; i<6; i++) {
      geoHashes.add(GeoHash.withCharacterPrecision(61.2 - i/100000, 21.5, 12).toBase32());
      geoHashes.add(GeoHash.withCharacterPrecision(61.2, 21.5 + i/100000, 12).toBase32());
    }
    return geoHashes;
}
```